# Plugin for automatic refreshing of vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin for QGIS which can automatically refresh all vector layers at a given interval of time. Prior to QGIS version 2.06 I was using self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh) along with timer which was working. The same does not seems to be working anymore with the current versions.

Can some please guide me how to go about it.

Comment: You don't need a plugin for that. Use `layer.triggerRepaint()` instead. It will work.